# C++: iterating over a list and an unordered_map in one loop

Tags: c++, list, iterator, unordered-map

In c++, I have a list of wstrings and an unordered wstring/wstring map.

```
std::list<std::wstring> m_L;
std::unordered_map<std::wstring, std::wstring> m_UM;
```

I need to run a loop over both lists and I don't want to repeat the loop code (in the unordered map, I only care about the first wstrings, not the second ones). Is there an iterator construct that would allow me to iterate over these two types in one loop? If I try to do this, I get "cannot deduce auto type" on auto* n:

```
for (auto* n : { &m_L, &m_UM }) {
    for (auto& it : *n) {
        ...
```

Comment: With C++20 or with `range-v3` I'm pretty sure you can have a concatenated view of both of those containers.

Comment: Instead of concentrating on what you would **not** like to deal with: In what order would that flattened 2D matrix you have be presented be listed in a 1D context? Can you present in/out examples to help us to help you?

Comment: The order in the map doesn't matter, as long as I go through all elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `C++20`'s `ranges` (or with [`range-v3`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library) you can do that rather trivially:

```
int main() {
    std::list<std::string> l_str = {"a", "b", "c"};
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m_str = {{"d", "dd"}, {"e", "ee"}};

    using namespace ranges::views; // for concat(), all() and keys()
    for (auto& e : concat(all(l_str), keys(m_str))) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output: `a b c e d`.

---

Note that I replaced `std::wstring` with `std::string`, but that should not make any real difference in the demonstration.

Comment: You get a mental downvote for the tune `a b c e d` but a real one anyway. :-)  Since this isn't tagged with a future version of C++, do you have any advice on how to adapt this to < C++20? Edit: the mental part is me - listening to metal - now

Comment: @TedLyngmo hey, it has the *`unordered`* in the name, doesn't it?! :D As for the adoption for **< `C++20`**, Eric's implementation that I linked works for `C++14`. It's a header-only library, so simple copy-paste or simple linking should be sufficient.

Comment: My only objection was to the music. `a b c e d`. :-)

I'll step away from the keyboard-phone for awhile now I think ...

Comment: @Fureeish Just to verify: is it ranges::views or ranges::view? With range-v3, I get "no member 'views'. 'view' seems OK. What I included: <range/v3/core.hpp>, <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>, <range/v3/view/all.hpp>, <range/v3/view/map.hpp>

Comment: @MrSparkly the folder itself is called `view`, but the namespace is called `views`. It used to be called `ranges::view`, but during the standarization the plural form was adopted. `ranges::views` should work for you. By the way, if you include `all.hpp`, there is no need for anything else :> You have already included *everything*.